# Get the default user name from a script run with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, user

I need to get this user name for my scripts that need to execute some commands without sudo with `sudo -u username foo`. But I need this username from the scripts executed with sudo.
How can I achieve that ?
(sorry if it's a bit confusing)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "execute some commands without sudo with `sudo -u username foo`?"

Comment: I mean I execute the script with sudo at the beginning with `sudo ./script.sh` but inside this script, I need to run some commands without sudo like running a pip package. That's why I wanted to switch user with this command `sudo -u username foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work with $SUDO_USER. Instead of using `sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" foo`, use instead `su - "SUDO_USER" -c "foo"` and I works better for example when running a pip package command.

Thank you Kamil Maciorowski and gnubeard for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a script with `sudo`, the tool will set the [`SUDO_USER`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/sudo.man.html#SUDO_USER) environment variable. Use it to retrieve the login name of the user who invoked `sudo`.

So inside a script you can do like this:

```
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" foo
```

But if `$SUDO_USER` is empty (e.g. the entire script is by mistake being run without `sudo`) then this will try to run `foo` as root. To prevent this, use the following snippet instead:

```
if [ "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
   sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" foo
else
   foo
fi
```

Comment: It seems to be working. But I get another error : `sudo: lastversion: command not found` (lastversion being a pip3 package). Maybe I need to open a new thread for that.

Comment: I've forgotten to say that this command is in a child script. This child script is called by a main script executed with sudo.